# Azure scheduler - dynamic content in POST

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler

Is it possible to use dynamic content in the POST body for a scheduled job in Azure scheduler?

I am writing a logic app that I would like to be able to pass a start time and a look back minute count to so that a failed invocation can be re-run across the same underlying data by passing the same parameters. I'm wondering if there are functions or operations similar to what can be found in logic apps for values such as `utcNow()`

Answer (score 0):

We do not support dynamic content in Scheduler, you may find some timestamp in the request header in the calls Scheduler made though.

Why are you not using Logic Apps when it can perform what you need?

Comment: Our client would like to use scheduler to trigger all integrations rather than internal schedulers within LAs. The argument is scheduler gives them a single place to orchestrate integration execution timelines.

Comment: Hi Josh, I'm not sure I understand. Logic Apps is built on top of Scheduler, so it has all the scheduling capability of Scheduler, plus many more functionality. If you don't mind, send me an email at Derek.Li (a) microsoft.com and we can discuss more about your specific scenarios.